# how to add and remove active class from component on scroll in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react and was trying to convert my dummy template to react, the problem is my java scrip are not working in react and I dont know exact how it work for react.
my old java script code that was working

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (function (e) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".category-section").forEach((function (e) {
           if (e.getBoundingClientRect().top < 75) {
              var t = e.attributes.id.value,
                 r = document.querySelector('[name="'.concat(t, '"]'));
              document.querySelectorAll(".categories-sidebar-item").forEach((function (e) {
                 return e.classList.remove("active")
              })), r.classList.add("active")
           }
        }))
     }), !0)
```

I have create a `<sideMenu/>` component for "categories-sidebar-item" in my react and rest code are in main container `<mainContainer/>`.

```
<div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-3 pr-0">
                        <SideMenu />       
                    </div>
              <div className="col-lg-6 category-products-section">
                    <div className="category-section" id="category-1">
                        <div className="fB d-c">
                            <div className="category-name-header sticky">
                                <div className="category-name">
                                    Festive Offer Best Ever
                                    <span className="cart-sidebar-badge">
                                        2
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="product-list flex d-column">
                                <div className="product-item flex a-center">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <div className="product-image-wrapper">
                                            <img loading="lazy" className="product-image bordered" src="images/image1.webp" />
                                            <div className="product-discount-badge">
                                                25% OFF
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have to tried using the `onScroll` event that react provides? An [example](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-onscroll)

Comment: can u provide me documentation or link as i am totally new to react

Comment: React provide event handlers for all event such as onClick, onBlur, onScroll, etc. You should use them as your component constantly re-render and your window.addListeners() will fail to pick up on changes to the DOM. Here's another [example](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-typescript-handling-onscroll-event/) you can look at on how to use the onScroll

Comment: also!! is it possible i can change class name of div inside child component <SideMenu /> on scroll change in main component <maincomponent/> or should i put the child component code directly in the main component.

Comment: What I would do is define the logic in your main component and pass the function as a prop to the child. There's many ways that you could do it but that is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

so I got it done, but as I am newbie to react, if anyone can improve this code or want to know the solution.

```
const[scroll , setScroll] = useState('category-1')
  
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
        document.querySelectorAll(".category-section").forEach((function (event){
        if(event.getBoundingClientRect().top < 75){
            var t = event.attributes.id.value;
            setScroll(t);
        } 
        }))
    });
}, []);
```

and hook it to the nav list

```
className={scroll == menu.id ? 'categories-sidebar-item active' : "categories-sidebar-item" }
```

Comment: Use const instead of var. Use `===` instead of `==` for type checking too.